# Toric Varieties as quotient of Lie groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

let $X_\Sigma$ be the toric variety of a smooth and complete fan $\Sigma$. Then $X_\Sigma$ has no toric factors and can nicely be represented as the quotient
$$X_\Sigma \simeq \left( \mathbb{C}^r - Z\right) / G$$
where the exceptional set $Z$ and the group $G$ (and its action on $\mathbb{C}^r - Z$) are determined by the fan $\Sigma$.

An example of this is the complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^n = \left( \mathbb{C}^{n+1} - 0 \right) / \mathbb{C}^\ast$ which is also known to satisfy $\mathbb{P}^n = U \left( n+1 \right) / \left( U \left( 1 \right) \times U \left( n \right) \right)$.

My question is know, whether one can find Lie groups $G$ and $H$ such that
$$ X_\Sigma \simeq H / G$$
for all toric varieties of the above type. If so, what exactly are these groups?

Thank you very much!